# Excel vba Error 5 Invalid procedure call or argument with power operand

Tags: vba, excel

Please consider this sub:

```
Sub TestPower()

    Dim dbl As Double

    dbl = -0.682434999562851

    Debug.Print (-0.682434999562851 ^ 0.2)
    Debug.Print (dbl ^ 0.2)
End Sub
```

On the second "debug.print" command, I'm getting an Error 5: Invalid procedure call or argument.

Excel Office 2016.

Any ideas?

Comment: While I found a workaround, I'm still interested to understand what's happening here. To bypass, I'm using: WorksheetFunction.Power(dbl, 0.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution to your problem:

```
Sub TestPower()
    Dim dbl As Double

    dbl = 0.682434999562851

    Debug.Print (-0.682434999562851 ^ 0.2)
    Debug.Print -(dbl ^ 0.2)
End Sub
```

Notice that I placed the negative sign outside the parenthesis (and changed dbl accordingly).

From the MSDN library, "A number can be negative only if exponent is an integer value."  I'm not a mathematician but it has something to do with the result being a Complex Number.

Comment: Thanks Brian! This definitely does the trick. I now apply the power operand on ABS(dbl) and negate afterwards if dbl was negative.

Answer (score 4):

What you are seeing has to do with operator precedence in VBA.

In VBA, exponentiation has a higher precedence than does negation.  So in your first equation, the exponentiation operation occurs first, and then the result is negated.

Actually, it seems the Power function is smarter than the exponentiation operator.  In point of fact, you are trying to take the fifth root of a negative number, which would be a real number.  The Power function recognizes that. The exponentiation operator does not.

**EDIT:** From VBA Help for the **^**:  Remarks A `number` can be negative only if `exponent` is an integer value.

*So it seems that the explanation for the behavior difference is, indeed, operator precedence, and a limitation of the VBA `^` operator.*

Comment: Thanks Ron. Great explanation.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that when you use the literal, VBA interprets the expression (-0.6824 ^ 0.2) as (-(0.6824 ^ 0.2)), but when you use the variable, it realizes you're trying to compute a fractional power of a negative number and gives up.