# floating exponentiation vba mac excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba, macos

Sorry this is my second question today, but I encoutered a very weird behavior (at least to me) and do not understand what is going on.

i have this very simple line of code:

```
res = 1 - (((beg - fin) / beg) ^ 2.5)
```

This causes an error :

> Run time error '5' : Invalid procedure call or argument.

If I replace the 2.5 by 2 then the error disappears. Eventually the 2.5 will also be a variable ( a very small one, around 0.001 ) but I changed with 2 when trying to identify the error.
Does anyone understand where the error is coming from?

Note : all variable are declared as double. I used a msgbox to retrieve the value of the variables and beg is around 79.01857 and fin is around 174.76

Thanks for your help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44932254/excel-vba-error-5-invalid-procedure-call-or-argument-with-power-operand

Comment: @braX , thanks for the comment, but while it is the same error, in the other post the issue is coming from a negative value but there is no negative number in my case. The work around worksheetfunction.power seems to work. I still have to check the numbers but I do not understand the issue in the first place

Comment: my bad stupid comment, of course I have negative values... sorry. 
Your comment was the exact explanation to my problem.